# file.write won't write to the file but normal text will - why is this happening?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

ive tested the code and when you enter just normal text into `file.write(self.info)` instead of `self.info` it works. But it will just not do anything if you leave it as `self.entry`.

````
    image = PhotoImage(file='C:/Users/plarkin2020334/Pictures/DQ_Logocp.png')
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        Label(self, image=self.image).place(relx=0, rely=0, anchor=NW)
        Label(self, text="Enter any additional Instructiuons for the day:", background="#3f49e5").place(relx=.0, rely=.45)
        self.info = str()
        self.entry = tkinter.Entry(self, textvariable=self.info).place(relx=.0, rely=.51)
        Button(self, text="Add to Todays List", command=self.add_list).place(relx=.0, rely=.61)


    def add_list(self):
        file = open("List.txt", "w")
        file.write(self.info)
        file.close()```
````

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are asking. Can you clarify what "when you enter just normal text into `file.write(self.info)` instead of `self.info` it works"? One of those is a method call with a value, and one is a value.

Comment: it does work yea if you just add "hi" will put it in the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close.

`self.info` should be an instance of tkinter.StringVar.  This is not the same thing as a str.  It's a special value for use in tkinter widgets, and it holds an instance of str.

To obtain the str that's inside a StringVar, call its get() function.

So:
Replace this line

```
self.info = str()
```

with:

```
self.info = tkinter.StringVar()
```

And replace:

```
file.write(self.info)
```

with:

```
file.write(self.info.get())
```